# why is my pc showing hidden files even after renaming files starting with a dot

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

My pc shows hidden files even after renaming the file with a name which starts with a dot is there any solution for this.

Comment: What have you tried? Do they show up in the terminal using `ls`? What happens if you press `ctrl+h`?

Comment: did you rename the file via menu -> rename or using `mv` command in terminal? Please edit your question, to add more information, regarding your OS and if hidden files/dot-files are always visible in nautilus. Also try `Ctrl`+`H`, to toggle hidden files [on] and [off]

Comment: yes exactly i have used hiding them via renaming them satrting with dot and pressed ctrl+h and the file disappears but it appears again when i reopen nautilus and again i should type ctrl+h to hide them

Comment: isnt there any permanent solution for this

Comment: @v2r what does a mv command mean

Comment: `mv`command stands for move/rename and can be used like this: `mv ~/Desktop/testfile.txt ~/Desktop/.testfile.txt`. This way you rename/ your file from `testfile.txt` to `.testfile.txt`.

Comment: can you say me how to follow the answer which is posted here @v2r

Comment: i cant get the oprtion of edit and where to get it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> Should toggle whether hidden files are visible.

To permanently change the setting in nautlius go

`Edit > Preferences > Views`

[image]

`And turn off: Show hidden and backup files`

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty documents rename it `.hidden`. Open it (Mousepad for xubuntu). Type the folder name you want to hide. I have attached a picture. Here `$RECYCLE.BIN`
and `System Volume Information` are hidden. So I type the name in `.hidden` file and put it in the folder where this two folders are currently in that I want to hide. After that hide the folders by `CTRL+H`. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: You welcome bro.. :)